# Paytm payments gateway testing stage not showing wallet, UPI payments options and invalid card details error

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am tring to integate paymt payments gateway in android and i have some queries:

1. Why it's not showing wallet, UPI options ?
2. Invalid card info error in debit and credit payment options net banking is working fine.
3. And if the payment is successful then from onTransactionResponse method i can get Success trx but how to know that the transaction is failed or not ?
4. And this line `PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();` showing `getStagingService
   (String) in PaytmPGService cannot be applied to ()`  error, but if i put `PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService("");` then it's works fine.

How to solve this problems ?

**<----------------------------->**

PaytmTransactionCallbacks

```
 @Override
    public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "onTransactionResponse: "+inResponse.toString());

        String s = inResponse.getString("STATUS");
        String oid = inResponse.getString("ORDERID");
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "onTransactionResponse: trxID: "+oid);

        if (s != null && s.equals("TXN_SUCCESS")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePostLimit(oid);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void networkNotAvailable() {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "networkNotAvailable: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "clientAuthenticationFailed: "+inErrorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "someUIErrorOccurred: "+inErrorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode, String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "onErrorLoadingWebPage: "+inErrorMessage+"    "+inFailingUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "onBackPressedCancelTransaction: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionCancel(String inErrorMessage, Bundle inResponse) {
        Log.d("paytm_gateway", "onTransactionCancel: "+inErrorMessage+"     res: "+inResponse);
    }
```

Comment: `getStagingService`  might be actually accepting some string param in call. Kindly check the latest library what all possible values they accept.

Comment: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk/ this is the official documentation and here `PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();` is written for testing.

Comment: I agree. But kindly click on and check in PaytmPGService class how they have definedl/implemented `getStagingService`

Comment: Ok, what about rest errors ?

Comment: @ShadowDroid i have checked it's asking for `payUrl` `public static synchronized PaytmPGService getStagingService(String payUrl)`

Comment: I am not posting this as answer Related to error 1 -  I have not used or implement Paytm SDK, so cannot comment on functionality and feature. For error 2 and 3 you will have to Edit Question and add exactly what error you are getting along with code you have implemented so far. I could only comment on error 4 because it is API mismatch.

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Has anyone yet figured out what value should be passed to getStagingService() method's payUrl parameter?